# Best way to setup my Angular project

Tags: angular, project-management

I'm an experienced Angular 1 developer now reading up on Angular 2. We're planning to do a big project that consists of a number of smaller 'overlapping' apps that use the same remote API. I'm interested in your opinion on how to setup this project with regards to proper project management, especially since my knowledge of git is limited.

Think of it a bit like Google's products where one user may or may not use several products with the same account. Some data and 'widgets' are used in multiple products, while some components are product-specific. It looks something like this (orange parts are reusable components across products):

[image]

More details:

- We don't have to worry about the backend API etc. That's all taken care of.
- There should be one 'container app' that handles auth, session etc and has a few menu items that allows the user to switch between products (preferably always staying in the container app).
- I'd like to manage products (all the gray dashed elements) seperately in terms of git and deploys (e.g. I don't want to have to deploy all my whitelabels every time I update one).
- I'd like to be able to have reusable smaller components that I can update throughout all projects in the workflow of editing one of my projects. So say I'm working on Customer Y's whitelabel and I want to edit one of my reusable components that I'm using in there, I don't want to open a separate project, push the updates and then pull the updates into my whitelabel project for every little change I make.

Questions:

1. What would this look like in terms of project management (git)?
2. Where do my services fit in that contact the API?

I hope this is a clear enough story. Please ask if I can explain anything better.

Comment: This is a great question but I'm afraid it might be a little bit too broad.  Also, bullet points 3 and 4 seem like they could contradict each other.  To be successful with this type of architecture, you should really be deploying your components as packages (npm / bower / etc) that you can version independently.  How you deploy really depends on what your continuous deployment configuration looks like (ie. Jenkins->Sinopia pipeline) but this also another long topic.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using `Angular CLI` - 
Angular cli is a command line interface to scaffold and build angular apps using nodejs style (commonJs) modules. Not only it provides you scalable project structure, instead it handles all common tedious tasks for you out of the box.

The Angular2 CLI makes it easy to create an application that already works, right out of the box. It already follows our best practices! Read more about it here: https://cli.angular.io/. Its a pretty simple and best way to get started with building Angular2 applications.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've actually already started using it and it's nice, but my question is more related to the overall architecture of a new multifaceted project.